# Calling one prototype method inside another in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

```
var Ob = function(){


}

Ob.prototype.add = function(){
    inc()

}

Ob.prototype.inc = function(){
    alert(' Inc called ');

}

window.onload = function(){
var o = new Ob();
o.add();
}
```

I would like to call something like this,how can i call, ofcourse i put **inc** as inner function to **add** I can do that but without having the inner function. how do i do that ?

Comment: "I can do that but without that, how do I do that" is awesome.

Comment: @Juhana forget about literal stuffs and be technical, this is a tech forum. and not grammar discussion.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's easy:

```
Ob.prototype.add = function(){
    this.inc()
}

Ob.prototype.inc = function(){
    alert(' Inc called ');
}
```

When you create the instance of `Ob` properties from prototype are copied to the object. If you want to access the methods of instance from within its another method you could use `this`.