# In javascript how can I call one prototype method in another prototype method?

Tags: javascript, call, prototype

suppose I have a function:

```
function test(){}

test.prototype.method01=function(){
    //do something
}

test.prototype.method02=function(){
    //how can I call the method01?
    //this.method01()...?
    //but the chrome through an error:
    //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'method01'
}
```

Edited:
in fact the method01 like this:

```
test.prototype.method02=function(){
    $('.cpy').resizable({

    }).draggable({
        start:function(e,ui){
            this.method01();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you assigning `method02` to an event of an image by any chance?

Comment: It depends on *how* you call `method02`. You should read the [MDN article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @pimvdb:I have improve my question,show how I call it

Comment: As so often in jQuery, inside the `start` callback, `this` refers to the element you call `draggable` on, in this case `.cpy`. You have to keep a reference to the `this` of `method02`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778874/calling-one-prototype-method-inside-another-in-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
test.prototype.method02=function(){
    var testThing = this;
    $('.cpy').resizable({

    }).draggable({
        start:function(e,ui){
            testThing.method01();
        }
    });
}
```

You have to preserve the `this` reference in another local variable so that the callback function can use it when calling the other method. The `this` reference is bound upon each and every function call, including calls to callback functions like the one you're using in the ".draggable()" setup. When that's called `this` will be set to something different from the `this` in your "method02" function.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, you could manually cache `this` in the lexical scope like other answers in this question suggest. However, the alternative that i would suggest is to create a bound method using `$.proxy` or `function.bind` as your call back.

Bound methods are always called with a stable `this`. I find them to be much more readable, than bizarrely named references to `this` in higher scopes

Answer (score 0):

whats about

```
test.prototype.method02=function(){
     this.method01.apply(this);
     // do some other stuff
}
```