# Re-apply event bindings after jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery

Unfortunately I can't create a jsFiddle because this requires a valid URL returning HTML but the point is I'm using an input mask , which stops working after execution of `$.load()`
I think it's me just not understanding this function very well.

script:

```
(function () {
    isa.uk.HpiLookup = (function () {
        function HpiLookup() { }
        HpiLookup.prototype.setupEventHandlers = function () {
            return $('#hpiLookupContainer').on("click", "#vehicleRegistrationSearchButton", this.onVehicleRegistrationSearchButton);
        };

        HpiLookup.prototype.setupInputMasks = function () {
            $('#VehicleRegistrationNumber').inputmask("#######", { "placeholder": "" });
        };

        HpiLookup.prototype.onVehicleRegistrationSearchButton = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return $('#hpiLookupContainer').load(
                GetVehicleByRegistrationNumberUrl,
                {
                    VehicleRegistrationNumber: $('#VehicleRegistrationNumber').val()
                },
                this.setupInputMasks);
        };

        return HpiLookup;

    })();
}).call(this);
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="hpiLookupContainer">
    <input id="VehicleRegistrationNumber" type="text">
    <button id="vehicleRegistrationSearchButton" type="button">Search</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var GetVehicleByRegistrationNumberUrl = '@Url.Action("GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber", "Vehicle")';
    var hpiLookup = new isa.uk.HpiLookup();
    hpiLookup.setupEventHandlers();
    hpiLookup.setupInputMasks();
</script>
```

I've tried to make $.load() callback the `setupInputMasks` this way but it won't. **How can I re-apply event bindings after `jQuery.load()`?**

Comment: Following the fortunes of `this` is giving me brain strain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the solution:

```
return $('#hpiLookupContainer').load(
    GetVehicleByRegistrationNumberUrl,
    {
        VehicleRegistrationNumber: $('#VehicleRegistrationNumber').val()
    },
    hpiLookup.setupInputMasks
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When You call `this.setupInputMasks);` it's `this` in current function not a class. Yuo should put some other variable ie: `self` and put `this` in.

An Explonation in Your code:

```
//...
HpiLookup.prototype.onVehicleRegistrationSearchButton = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var self = this; // Now You put this (from a class) into another variable
        return $('#hpiLookupContainer').load(
            GetVehicleByRegistrationNumberUrl,
            {
                VehicleRegistrationNumber: $('#VehicleRegistrationNumber').val()
            },
            function(){self.setupInputMasks}); // now You call class this
    };
// ...
```

It sholud help You. You can also use jQuery solution, function proxy.

More is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: thanks. it doesn't appear to be loading the html returned from server because of the callback function. If I move `self.setupInputMasks` out of the `$('#hpiLookupContainer').load()`, it won't be called.

Comment: @Chuck - try the code now, I've update: `self.setupInputMasks` to `function(){self.setupInputMasks}`. This should help.

Comment: doesn't work dude. `self` is a button and setupInputMasks is `undefined`. i've tried moving `var self = this;` out of the function and then it becomes a `Window`, which is also wrong. Why isn't it as simple as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778874

Comment: Your welcom. Glad that You have found the solution.