# calling a prototype method from another - getting 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In brevity, this is how my Nodejs controller looks

I am trying to call 'getFqUrl' from another prototype method 'getData' using this. but am getting 'undefined' error.

I referred to this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778874/calling-one-prototype-method-inside-another-in-javascript) and to me, my code looks exactly the same.

```
    function SolrFacetClient() {
        this.fieldNames = fieldNames;
        this.facets = new Map();
    }
    SolrFacetClient.prototype.getFqUrl = function(fq){
        var url = '&fq=';
        console.log(fq);
    }
    SolrFacetClient.prototype.getData = function (fieldName,fq) {
        var a = this.getFqUrl;
        console.log(a(fq)); //this doesn't work. getting 'undefined' 
    }
    SolrFacetClient.prototype.init = function (fq) {
      //Updated this section after question was posted.
      //this works
        var aRef =   this.getFqUrl;
        aRef(fq);
       //Update ends    
        var getSolrData = this.getData;
        return getSolrData(item,fq);
    };
    exports.facets = function (req, res) {
        var facetClient = new SolrFacetClient();
        var fq = new Map();
        facetClient.getFqUrl(fq); //this works 

        when(facetClient.init(fq), function(result){
            res.jsonp(result);
        })
    }
```

Comment: You can't just call `a` without providing a context, as in `a.call(this, fq)` to take one example.

Comment: I tried a(this,fq) as suggested and even that didn't work. In my code, if you notice, I do the samething with 'getData' that is being called from 'init' which works

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn how `this` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you separate a function from an object context and call it, the result is that the value of `this` in the called function won't be what it was written to expect.

Thus, in this code:

```
    var getSolrData = this.getData;
    return getSolrData(item,fq);
```

things would work correctly if it looked like

```
    return this.getData(item, fq);
```

It does not work in your version, however, because the `getData()` function expects `this` to refer to an object instance. Unlike a lot of other programming languages, JavaScript doesn't maintain any long-term relationship between a function and any particular object (or "class", which is a tricky term to use in JavaScript) unless you explicitly ask for that with `.bind()` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. my question is a proof for 'too little knowledge..' I used 'getSolrData'  because I was calling another function from where the context of 'this' changed (that I understood from your explanation).'return all(this.fieldNames.map(function(item){var aPromise = getSolrData(item,fq);return aPromise;}))'
I updated 'init' in my code(question updated) and noticed that the same is working here. If you could, could you help me understand? I also got a link to MDN document that I will refer, Thanks

Comment: @patb23 the problem is that there's a very important difference between calling a function via `object.someFunction()` and calling it without the object reference. When you call the function without the object reference, then inside the called function `this` will be a reference to `window` and not the object. Thus, inside `getData` that reference to `this` will result in an `undefined` value.

Comment: Kind of understood. Thanks for the explanation. In my code, I have this 'facetClient.init(fq)' which provides the needed context. Thanks again

Comment: @patb23 yes but then inside `init()` you call `getData()` via that local `getSolrData()` variable. Because you make that function call without the object context, inside `getData()` the value of `this` will be `window`. The fact that your code makes the function call with a correct value of `this` in scope makes no difference - the function call itself must look like `this.getData(item, fq)` for it to work.